# New to Hadoop MapReduce, getting a NoSuchMethodException on mapred.Reducer.<init>()

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, nosuchmethoderror

Solution: Use a better tutorial- http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.22.0/mapred_tutorial.html

I just started working with MapReduce, and I'm running into a weird bug that I haven't been able to answer through Google. I'm making a basic WordCount program, but when I run it, I get the following error during Reduce:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer.<init>()
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:485)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

The WordCount program is the one from the Apache MapReduce tutorial. I'm running Hadoop 1.0.3 in pseudo-distributed mode on Mountain Lion, all of which I think is working fine since the examples are all executing normally. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my code for reference:

```
package mrt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException{

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            output.collect(word,one);
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOException{

        int sum = 0;

        while(values.hasNext()){
            sum += values.next().get();
        }

        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("Wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not your choice of API. Both the stable (mapred.*) and the evolving (mapreduce.*) APIs are fully supported and the framework itself carries tests for both to ensure no regressions/breakage across releases.

The problem is this line:

```
conf.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
```

You're setting the Reducer interface there as the Reducer, when you should be setting your implementation of the Reducer interface instead. Changing it to:

```
conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
```

Will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you're using the hadoop.mapreduce package instead of the hadoop.mapred package.  The mapred package is older and has different methods on the classes than do the current version mapreduce classes.

Comment: I'm currently using the hadoop.mapred package because that's what the tutorial used. Switching to hadoop.mapreduce causes errors on MapReduceBase, Mapper, Reducer, and a few more. Is the switch necessary, or will hadoop.mapred still work?

Comment: The use of the package needs to be consistent within a single job.    If everything matches up I'll withdraw the answer.

Comment: You were right actually, turns out the mapred package doesn't work any more. Managed to find a newer tutorial which uses the mapreduce package, not sure why it isn't the default on Apache's site. Regardless though, it works. Thanks!